# Sum of pairwise distance after applying normalized adjacency matrix to values

Tags: graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

I have $N$ values defined on a graph with $N$ nodes called $x_i$ for node $i$. I define the pairwise distance between these values as follow:

$D(x) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}||x_i - x_j||_2 $

Now, I will multiply the normalized adjacency matrix (with self-loops) and define new values for each node as follow:

$y_i = \sum\limits_{j\in Neighbors(i)} a_{ij}x_j$

where $a_{ij}$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{d_id_j}}$ if there is an edge between node $i$ and node $j$ and zero otherwise (remember we have also self-edges)

Is there any way to prove that D(y) is less than D(x)? I mean:

$\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}||y_i - y_j||_2  \leq \sum_{i,j}a_{ij}||x_i - x_j||_2 $

It is really intuitive for me. But I cannot prove it mathematically. I would appreciate any hint or suggestion.

Comment: @caduk Thanks for your comment. I think you forgot the self-loop. But thanks, I found out that I did a mistake in the definition.

Comment: If you take a star $S_n$ with weight 0 in center and 1 on leaves. $D(x) = \frac{n}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $y_i =  1$ for every leaf and $\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}}$ for the center vertex, so $D(y) = \frac{n}{\sqrt{n}} \frac{(n-\sqrt{n})^2}{\sqrt{n}^2} = \mathcal{O}(\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n}})$ - Edit : oh, if it's $||.||_2$, then it add a square root, so nevermind

Comment: No, even with $||.||_2$, $D(y)$ is still $\mathcal{O}(n)$...

Comment: $D(x) = \frac{n}{\sqrt{n}}$ is right. But why $y_i = 1$? the degree of leaves is equal to $2$. so $y_i$ should be $\frac{1}{2}$ for leaves, and $\frac{n}{\sqrt{2(n+1)}}$, right? so $D(y)$ will be of O(n) again.